# Angular 2 get headers in onInit

Tags: angular, http-headers

I'm developing on an Angular2 project and I've a problem regarding headers in http request. This is my scenario: I've a main page already developed, in a project I can't work on, with a menu in which every item redirects on various pages I'm developing. The main page, on every redirect call, sets a field in the header. Using Explorer developer tool I can see the first call on redirect with field setted in header and the http request is something like this:

```
https://myProject/main
```

My question is: can I get headers on onInit function of my page?
I tried to make an http request to `https://myProject/main` in onInit function but it returns 302 error.
Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
The main page is not part of my project.

Answer (score 0):

> I think you have to look into angular routing and navigation.

A http redirect call is not required unless the page you are trying to load is not developed within your application.

[Angular routing and navigation reference](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The main page is in a different project. My pages are in my own project.